# Is it possible to send parameter to just one function (in DLL) in way that other functions (in DLL) will know value of this parameter?

Tags: c

I export functions from DLL and all of them need the same parameter (number `N` (integer)).
DLL function are called from LabVIEW always in same order (`initialization`, `calculation` `clean up`)

Is it possible to set parameter `N` just once? I mean just send it to `initialization` and somehow export it to the rest of functions? So it is not necessary to send `N` to all function manually.

```
extern "C" __declspec(export) void initialization( int N ){
  do initialization with N
}

extern "C" __declspec(export) void calculation(){
  I would like to use N here but keep calculation()
}

extern "C" __declspec(export) void clean_up(){
  I would like to use N here but keep clean_up()
}
```

Comment: Well, store your `N` somewhere (in a context structure that you'll pass around or *shrug* as a global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your variable a global, set it from the `initialization` method, and then just retrieve it inside the other methods.

You do this by declaring it `extern` and defining it in a single `.c` file.